# MySQL select row and join to multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables and can't get my MySQL Query to work:

```
First Table users:
user_id name
------------
1       Bob
2       Alice

Second Table fields:
id unser_id field_id value
-----------------------------
1  1        4           foo
2  1        5           10
3  2        4           bar
```

Now I would like to join the Tables in a way that outputs:

```
[0] => (
          [user_id] => 1
          [name] => Bob
          [fields] => (
                         [4] => foo
                         [5] => 10
                      )
[1] => (
          [user_id] => 2
          [name] => Alice
          [fields] => (
                         [4] => bar
                      )
       )
```

Thanks a lot!

I tried:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
       u.name 
FROM   users as u 
INNER JOIN fields as f on u.user_id = d.user_id
```

But I get for every user just the first fields entry.

Comment: I urge you to post your code as well.  Telling us what you would like to happen isn't as useful as showing us how you are trying to make it happen.

Comment: It`s unser_id or user id in fields table?

Comment: Its user_id, the id in fields table is the unique index of the field row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id,name,GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ',')as field FROM users u JOIN fields f 
ON u.user_id=f.unser_id GROUP BY user_id
```

Maybe something like this?

Comment: Hi, yes, but i would like to map the f.value with the f.field_id, that would be nice.

Comment: I think i can use two times GROUP_CONCAT, works fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.user_id,u.name,f.field_id,f.value from users u LEFT JOIN fields f ON u.user_id = f.unser_id
```

Comment: Hi, this one outputs only the first row of the field.